# Are there any tools to export a network structure in TensorFlow to eps/pdf file for paper?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Sometimes we need to draw the network structure in article, so are there any useful tools to do this work perfectly for the network? I tried the `Download as PNG` provided in tensorboard, but it seems not very good for paper.

Comment: There is some work in progress to do an export in dot/tikz for LaTeX, you can follow the advancement on this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/570)

Comment: @Lescurel, thanks for pointing that out! I'll close this post.